# Bash read 1000 lines of a file at a time until complete

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am executing a `bash` script on a `txt` file that contains 10,000 lines.

Instead of `split` a file up into individual files with 1000 lines each and executing my loop over these splits, I would like to read 1000 lines at a time and run a function, then read the next 1000 lines and so on until the file has been read.

I tried `head` the file and then `sed` these lines out to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What operation do you want to do on the individual chunks of those 1000 lines? The solution could be optimized based on your usage.

Comment: *run a function* - what that function should do?

Comment: cat "$ZONE".txt | jq -c '.EdgeStartTimestamp=(.EdgeStartTimestamp/1000000 | floor) | .EdgeEndTimestamp=(.EdgeEndTimestamp/1000000 | floor) |{"index": {"_index": "timeordered", "_type": "logs", "_id": .RayID, "pipeline": "geoip-timeordered"}}, .' | curl -s -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty --data-binary @- > /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: That is the above command that outputs the full file - I need to split this in to lines of 5000

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: @MatthewBullock, do you want to split `"$ZONE".txt` up in 1000-line chunks, or do you want the JSON that you post to be in 1000-line chunks? If the latter, is it important to keep the JSON correctly formatted, or are you just looking for the split? How about showing us your attempt (in your question please) with some sample input and expected output, perhaps with a smaller chunk size? A solution that chunks at 3 lines should be expandable to 1000 lines easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to pass the individual chunks to your function. use a while loop
like this.

```
i=1
chunk_file="yourfile.txt"
j=$(($i + 1000 - 1 ))
total_lines=`wc -l $yourfile | awk '{print $1}'`
#total_lines=10000
while [[ $i -le $total_lines ]]
do
echo $i,$j
sed -n "$i,$j p"  > ${chunk_file}
yourfunction ${chunk_file}

i=$(( $j + 1))
j=$(($i + 1000 - 1 ))

done
```